# Como adaptar uma div com position: fixed?

Tags: css

Tenho uma *div* com `position: fixed`. Como faço para o `height`(Altura) se adaptar de acordo com a resolução da tela?

Comment: Se adaptar como exatamente?

Comment: Por exemplo, tenho um formulário com uma div position:fixed Ok? Se eu exibo esse formulário em uma resolução por exemplo 1920x1080, o mesmo mostra todos os campos normalmente, no entanto, se eu exibo esse mesmo formulário em uma resolução 1024x768 alguns campos não são exibidos, pois a tela está fixa, e não tem como exibi-las.

Comment: Nesse caso você precisa retirar o `position: fixed` (com uma media query), senão o conteúdo vai ficar cortado nessas resoluções.

Comment: Ou então utilize percentagens.

Answer (score -1):

É isto que pretendes?
Os numeros só estão lá para poderes ter um scroll na página e ver o elemento fixo...

http://jsfiddle.net/hy3cjazu/

```css
.fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
1<br/>
2<br/>
3<br/>
4<br/>
5<br/>
6<br/>
7<br/>
8<br/>
9<br/>
10<br/>
11<br/>
12<br/>
13<br/>
14<br/>
15<br/>
16<br/>
17<br/>
18<br/>
19<br/>
20<br/>
21<br/>
22<br/>
23<br/>
24<br/>
25<br/>
26<br/>
27<br/>
28<br/>
29<br/>
30<br/>
31<br/>
32<br/>
33<br/>
34<br/>
35<br/>
<div class="fixed">CONTEUDO</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/9u1gxquf/1/

Veja este fiddle e diga-me se é o que procura.

A div da direita, ou seja `right` é uma div de exemplo com as especificações pedidas

```
.right{
   width:100px;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   color:white;
   height: 40%;
   position:fixed;
   right:0;
   top:40%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

O que eu fiz foi, dei uma altura em % para que quando a página encolhesse, escondesse o resto dos inputs, ou seja os com borda azul. Deste modo ele irá esconder devido à presença do overflow:hidden;

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/131880)

Comment: @rLinhares Editei a pergunta, acha que tenho mais alguma coisa a mostrar? Tentei explicar um pouco o que fiz e mostrei a css a alterar.

Comment: a questão é que deve-se evitar respostas por link; o link é legal pra servir como referência mas a resposta deve conter "a resposta".

Comment: @rLinhares Mas a resposta está bem indicada agora ou devo explicar mais?

Comment: @rLinhares Como eu notei o -1 na resposta, pensei que fosse por estar mal reformulada por isso é que perguntei.

Comment: @rLinhares Mas obrigado pelo que disse, vou tentar melhorar as respostas